# HTML elements that are not block and not inline

Tags: html, element

I just learned that there are two types of HTML elements: Block elements and inline elements. Please see the definition [here](http://www.w3resource.com/html/HTML-block-level-and-inline-elements.php).

It appears to me there must be a third kind of HTML elements that are used outside of `<body>` (e.g. `<head>` and `<title>`).

Do these elements have a name too? Which?

Comment: Since "block element" and "inline element" seem to be named for their default CSS `display` value, following the pattern would mean that `<head>` is a "none element"... perhaps better as a "hidden element". Note also that "hidden elements" can appear in the `<body>`, such as `<script>` or even `<input type="hidden" />`.

Comment: Also fun fact: you can actually set CSS `head, title {display:block}` to make the title of the page visible on the page itself. Not that you should...

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: If you make your comment an answer I can accept it.